# Add multiple tags to marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Created i model like in answer. 
Also added tags in markers:

```
 MarkerTag tag = new MarkerTag();
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.045029, 28.861427))
            .title("Marker")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
    tag.setEmail("first@gmail.com");
    tag.setPhoneNumber("+37369490007");
    marker.setTag(tag);
    Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.000327, 28.867950))
            .title("Marker")
            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400 fdfsfsfsdfsfdsfsfssfsfsfsfsfs"));
    tag.setEmail("second@gmail.com");
    tag.setPhoneNumber("+37368750588");
    marker2.setTag(tag);
    Marker marker3 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.024204, 28.889236))
            .title("Marker")
            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400 /n dasdasdas d"));
    tag.setEmail("three@gmail.com");
    tag.setPhoneNumber("+37369339092");
    marker3.setTag(tag);
```

And added my methods:

```
private void makeCall(Marker marker) {
    MarkerTag tag = ((MarkerTag)marker.getTag());
    if (tag != null) {
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + String.valueOf(tag.getPhoneNumber())));
        startActivity(call);
    }
}
private void sendEmail(Marker marker) {
    MarkerTag tag = ((MarkerTag)marker.getTag());
    if (tag != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("email:" + String.valueOf(tag.getEmail())));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        checkAndStart(this, intent, R.string.action_settings);
    }
}
```

But now when i press on markers i get just one number, this

> 37369339092
>   and when i try to send email i catched the error :
>   233 26548-26548/com.vm.sai E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                               Process: com.vm.sai, PID: 26548
>                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.getTag()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                   at com.vm.sai.activities.MapsActivity.sendEmail(MapsActivity.java:168)
>                                                                   at com.vm.sai.activities.MapsActivity.-wrap1(MapsActivity.java)
>                                                                   at com.vm.sai.activities.MapsActivity$2.onClickConfirmed(MapsActivity.java:92)
>                                                                   at com.vm.sai.utils.OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener$1.run(OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener.java:84)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

Answer (score 4):

The `.setTag()` accept an `object`. So, in order to add more information in there you just have to create your own TagObject, lets call it MarkerTag;

```
public class MarkerTag {


    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public MarkerTag() {

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Then you just add it to your marker as a tag:

```
MarkerTag yourMarkerTag = new MarkerTag();
yourMarkerTag.setEmail("someemail@gmail.com");
yourMarkerTag.setPhoneNumber("+15552345353");
marker.setTag(yourMarkerTag);
```

Now to get it back you just have to make sure that you are getting the right

```
    if(null != marker.getTag()){
    if(marker.getTag() instanceof MarkerTag){
        MarkerTag yourMarkerTag = ((MarkerTag)marker.getTag());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity, yourMarkerTag.getEmail() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity, yourMarkerTag.getPhoneNumber() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it s great. But i mean that i need to add 2 fields at my marker info, like a marker.setTag("+37369490007"); marker.setTag("+someemail@gmail.com");

Comment: @Inkognito ... please check the edit. Also, no you can't put too different tags the way you are trying to do it. if you are in need of a lot of extra association data other than the location data then you have to create an object and put those data in it and pass it to the marker as a tag.

Comment: @Inkognito ... also, please mark it as an answer so future developers benefit from it

Comment: Updated the answer, try to do like yours example

Comment: @Inkognito  you obviously need to check if the marker actually have a Tag or not ... I'll updated my answer so you would see that it wrong

Comment: sorry, i try and this way, but doesn t work correctly((

Comment: Onve you create the marker, do you ever remove them or reset the map

Comment: Nope, it fixed markers. I can show you all code(MapsActivity) in chat, mb you show my mistake.

Comment: May I have your Gmail so I can chat with you on Google Hangout... Send it to me in the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138650/discussion-between-mohammedalsafwan-and-inkognito).